# Is this equality for derivatives true?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I was trying to solve a problem and I came across the **left term** in the equality below (which is part of a differential equation), were $\mu$ is a constant:

$$\frac{d(\mu·\frac{du}{dy})}{dy}=\mu·\frac{d^2u}{dy^2}$$

In order to solve it and be able to integrate after I was wondering if the equality presented above is true (which, as I see it, is mainly a change in notation to see things clearer, no big deal operations and equalities going on here). The thing is that, as obvious as it may seem, I am having trouble on determining how the $d()$ affects $\mu·\frac{du}{dy}$

$$d(\mu·\frac{du}{dy})$$

Is the **left term** $=$ **right term**? How does the $d()$ affect $\mu·\frac{du}{dy}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the definition of the derivative.

\begin{equation}f'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}\end{equation}

Next, let's introduce multiplication by $\mu$.

\begin{equation}g(x) = \mu f(x)\end{equation}
\begin{equation}g'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{\mu f(x + h) - \mu f(x)}{h}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}g'(x) = \mu\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}g'(x) = \mu f'(x)\end{equation}
\begin{equation}(\mu f(x))' = \mu f'(x)\end{equation}

So yes, you can pull out the $\mu$.

The **left term** $=$ **right term**.